# Expressing “If $8$ does not divide $x^2−1$, then $x$ is even.” in formal language and negate it.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

I am trying to solve the question **4.18)** on the book *Reading, Writing, and Proving: A Closer Look at Mathematics* 2nd ed. on page 44.

The following is the question.

---

For an integer $x$ consider the statement: “If $8$ does not divide $x^2−1$, then $x$ is even.”

(a) State an appropriate universe for $x$.

(b) Write the statement in symbols.

(c) Negate the statement.

---

The following is my attempted solution.

---

a) An appropriate universe for $x$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

b) $\forall x,((x\in \mathbb{Z} \wedge \forall y,(y \in \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow y\ne \frac{x^2 - 1}{8})) \rightarrow \exists m,(m\in \mathbb{Z} \wedge x = 2m)).$

c) $\exists x,((x \in \mathbb{Z} \wedge  \forall y,(y \in \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow y\ne \frac{x^2 - 1}{8}) \wedge  \forall m,(m \in \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow x \ne 2m)).$ The statement can be translated in plain English language as "There exists a real number $x$ such that $x$ is an integer, $8$ does not divide $x^2 -1$, and $x$ is not even."

---

I need help verifying my answer.

Reference:

Daepp, U., & Gorkin, P. (2011). *Reading, writing, and proving*: A closer look at mathematics. In *Reading, writing, and proving: A closer look at mathematics* (2nd ed., p. 44). New York: Springer.

Comment: The statement requires $x$ to be an integer, not a general real number.

Comment: @lulu Can't I use $\forall x,(x\in \mathbb{Z})$ to denote "For all real number $x$, $x$ is an integer."?

Comment: But then why situate $x$ amongst the reals to start?  What's special about $\mathbb R$ here?  Why not $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lulu noted, for a) you could nominate $\Bbb Z$, which would make the statement true, whereas your choice makes its negation true instead. Having said that, whether the statement is true or false isn't the point of the exercise.

In a universe $U$ we can write $\forall x(8\nmid x^2-1\to2|x)$ for (b); we need not mention membership of $U$. Even if we did, we'd expand $\forall x(\phi(x))$ as $\forall x\in U(\phi(x))$ or $\forall x(x\in U\to\phi(x))$, no commas needed. These $U$-mentioning approaches have two related disadvantages: they require $U$ to be an object that can appear in this formalism, and if we're making $x\in U$ an antecedent it raises the question of what $\forall$ runs over.

With my recommended concision, the negation can be written in (c) as $\exists x(8|x^2-1\land 2\nmid x)$.

Answer (score 1):

a. "$x$ is an **integer**": $x\in \Bbb Z$

b. Split by high-level/low-level construct on divisibility:
(1) "$8$ does not divide $x^2-1$": $8\not\mid (x^2-1)\quad$ OR $\quad \not\exists k\in\Bbb Z:8k=x^2-1 \quad$ OR $ \quad \forall k\in\Bbb Z:8k\neq x^2-1$
(2) "if... then": $\implies$
(3) "$x$ is even": $2\mid x \quad$ OR $\quad  \exists j\in\Bbb Z:2j=x$

The use of division in an integer universe is a little suspect, hence the use of multiplication above.

The claim is that this is always true, so $\forall x\in \Bbb Z:(\forall k\in\Bbb Z:8k\neq x^2-1) \implies (\exists j\in\Bbb Z:2j=x)$

c. The claim is in fact true, so negation will produce a false claim; you seem to have made a valid negation of your preceding statement, although there are several ways to do this.

Note there are variations on symbols and preferred usage, which changes over time also, so don't be surprised to see some slightly different answers both here and elsewhere.